# How to remove ambiguity in grammar using CUP?

Tags: java, parsing, lalr, cup

I have this grammar

```
S-> Stat
Stat -> Exprs WRITE
Stat -> Vars READ
Vars -> ID COMMA Vars
Vars -> ID
Exprs -> Expr COMMA Exprs
Exprs -> Expr
Expr -> ID
Expr -> ...
...
```

(You can test it here  http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/lalr1.html)

The grammar is ambiguous and it produces S/R conflicts, but the real problem comes out with input `ID COMMA ID WRITE` meanwhile with `ID COMMA ID READ` the parser works.

Is there a way to prevent this without change the grammar in CUP?

Comment: There's no way to fix it without changing the grammar. But there is a fix without changing the language. It's a bit annoying, though, and it needs more details about  `Expr`

Comment: There's a sketch of how to do this sort of thing with an LALR(1) parser at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248575/eliminating-grammar-ambiguity-when-a-rule-covers-a-subset-of-another/35249521#35249521).